# Getting wrong result from php math functions

Tags: php

It was supposed to show a result of "5.712" (actually it is 237.12, the correct  $b3 = 750000; ) but instead it shows "0.118"

Help needed....

```
<?php

#This is the Excel formula "=((B4*B5-B3)/(B5/12))/B3*100"#

$b3 = 75000;
$b4 = 16070;
$b5 = 60;
$d = 1;
$e = 10;

$p = ( $b4 * $b5) - $b3  / ( $b5 / 12 ) / ( $b3 * 100 );

print ''.$p.' ';



?>
```

Comment: Really has nothing to do with excel.. These aren't "excel functions". They are normal math functions. My guess is your order of operations are not what you expect though.

Comment: You have your `(` and `)` in different places ...

Comment: DavidPostill@ can you correct the  code please ?

Comment: @DavidPostill Ah yes I didn't look at it that carefully to see that. I see it now. Shijil look at your two formulas and how the brackets differ.

Comment: @Shijil Why should I correct your incorrect code? It changes your question.

Comment: Software development questions are off-topic for this website. You clearly have the correct logic in your PHP comment; so how in the world did you manage to screw it up when converting to PHP?

Comment: I don't see how it is supposed to show `5.712` instead of `237.12` and showed `0.118` instead of `964200`

Comment: Generally, programming questions belong at Stack Overflow. I would recommend polishing up your formatting and description first, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a careful look at your brackets:

Excel:

```
"=((B4*B5-B3)/(B5/12))/B3*100"#
```

PHP:

```
$p = ( $b4 * $b5) - $b3  / ( $b5 / 12 ) / ( $b3 * 100 );
```

Change your formula to:

```
$p = (( $b4 * $b5 - $b3)  / ( $b5 / 12 )) / ( $b3 * 100 );
```

**Be careful with your parenthesis always!**

[image]

Comment: Really? With `.../B3*100` become `... / ( $b3 * 100 )`?

Comment: @TomYan You should also look more carefully at the difference in parenthesis :D

Comment: No, I think YOU should look more carefully :D

Comment: I see more than that as a difference...

Comment: Since when `X / Y * Z` is the same as `X / (Y * Z)`?

Comment: lol you still don't see it. That's ok. I am done here as it helped the OP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37065/discussion-between-tom-yan-and-eric-f).

Comment: Never mind, two php test sites with your lines straightly copied and pasted to it tells that I am right, just like Excel did. Silly me, why the hell was I even testing just because of two random guys giving and confirming an irrational answer. At least I confirmed it's not some secret in PHP that I didn't know though.

Comment: @TomYan Sure. You are not understanding what I am saying. You are focusing on the wrong part. Why do you care so much if I correctly answered the OP?  Are you suggesting our PHP isn't doing it correctly? I DID answer his question correctly to get his desired result so why are you all bent out of shape you can't get my answer to work for you? If you have a problem, ask your own question

Comment: @EricF I am sure you magically know why the OP got 0.118 in the first place, coz apparently you guys are telepathically connected in encrypted channel that outsiders will get confused by.

Comment: @EricF Oh so my stupidity isn't on even maths / PHP / Excel formula, but on being rational on this site. Great. Thanks for the lesson.

Comment: @TomYan Glad you recognize where the problem is at least :)

Comment: @EricF Doesn't help though. I'll remain stupid for the rest of my life :)